# child divs will fill parent div

Tags: html, css

I have **N** pieces of non-fixed width child `div`s. And I have a non-fixed width parent `div`. I want to fill and align the child `div`s in parent `div` side by side such as `td - tr` relationship. How can I do that?

Comment: Here you are
http://jsfiddle.net/VTpFS/

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` for the child elements. At the first element of a new row use `clear:both`.

Comment: Actually the view has to be like the tables in example. Because childs can increase or decrease. Divs act like a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/5LcZv/

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left for the child elements, but instead of using a :first with a clear:both;, use a div with a class of "clearfix" - ( see below ) and put the clear:both; in the css.

Markup for div between rows -

```
<div class="clearfix">
```

CSS relating to the div

```
.clearfix{

    clear:both;

}
```

Comment: Actually the view has to be like the tables in example. Because childs can increase or decrease. Divs act like a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/5LcZv/

Comment: I see, I was approaching from a slightly more fluid way of doing things, thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You say non-fixed width and nothing about height. The tr-td relationship is special and if that is exactly what you want you can display objects like table-row/table-cell etc.

Here you can see the difference of code below, in action: http://jsfiddle.net/zv5KF/

```
body
{
font-size:10px;
}
.table
{
display:table;
border:1px solid black;
/*width:500px;*/
}
.tr
{
display:table-row;
}
.td
{
display:table-cell;
border:1px solid red;
<body>

<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
<div class="td" style="width:10px;height:10px;">They're</div>
<div class="td" style="width:50px;height:10px;">all</div>
<div class="td" style="width:100px;height:100px;">like</div>
<div class="td" style="width:25px;height:25px;">hello</div>
<div class="td">and</div>
<div class="td">hi</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid black;">
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red; width:10px;height:10px;">They're</div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red; width:50px;height:10px;">all</div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;">like</div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red;width:25px;height:25px;">hello</div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red;width:25px;height:25px;">and</div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red;">hi</div>
</div>

</body>
```